# Why does the alert-box keep firing in the following code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-events, onblur

I have the following HTML code:

```js
function presence_check(elem) {
  if ($(elem).val() === "") {
    alert("Please enter something");
    $(elem).focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Don't leave this textbox blank" onblur="presence_check(this)">
<input type="text" placeholder="Secon input box">
```

The code is supposed to alert the user and re-focus on the element if the textbox is empty, but instead, it continuously fires the onblur event. I have seen some answers saying that when the alert-box pops up, it removes the focus on the element, consequently firing the onblur event. However, I don't understand how that is possible since the alert() function is called after the element has already lost focus

Comment: what is your intended behavior?

Comment: @NabeelKhan it's in the question: `The code is supposed to alert the user and re-focus on the element if the textbox is empty`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because on `blur` the `alert()` is shown. You then put the focus *back* in to the element ready for the `blur` to fire again when the use clicks a button in the dialog, hence an infinite loop. You can see this happening in the console output in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/89ydL673/)

This is a prime example of why you should never use `alert()` in any system - even for debugging purposes. Use an actual HTML element to display the warning to the user, and `console.log()` or `console.dir()` for debugging. Here's an example of how to do this:

```js
$('input.validate').on('blur input', function() {
  var $message = $(this).next('.validation-message');
  if (this.value.trim() === "") {
    $message.show();
    this.focus();
  } else {
    $message.hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.validation-message {
  display: none;
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Don't leave this textbox blank" class="validate" />
  <span class="validation-message">Please enter something</span>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Second input box" />
</div>
```

I would also strongly suggest you don't force the focus back in to the field when it's invalid as it prevents the user from doing anything else in your page, which is terrible UX.

When you do that the JS can be simplified to just this:

```
$('input.validate').on('blur input', function() {
  $(this).next('.validation-message').toggle(this.value.trim() === '');
});
```